# 500 (Internal Server Error) when making a post request in Angular

Tags: django, angular, typescript, post, internal-server-error

I am getting 500 (Internal Server Error) when I try make post request to Django server, the two get and put requests makes successfully, in Django I connected to PostgreSQL,

component.ts:

```
export class UsersComponent  implements OnInit{

  users!: any[]

  user:any = {
    fullname:'',
    email:'',
    car:''
  };

  constructor(public userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getUserData()
  }

  onCreate(){
      this.userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe(
        (response:any) =>{
          console.log('user created succesfully');
          this.getUserData();
        },
        (error:any)=>{
          console.error('errror',error);
        }
      );
  }


  getUserData(){
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.users = data
    })
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
export class UserService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user'

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
 
  createUser(user:any){
      return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, user)
  }
}
```

Django models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=55)
    car = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you server is accepting POST requests. Maybe you have to allow requests by this verb

Comment: Yes , in django server post request works , but works little bit wrong, it makes post request to api/user/, so  its creates a new object, but when if i refresh page it creates a new identical object but with id + 1